# load form submit results in same div

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

i have a form that loads a table in a form with a submit button 
i want that form to display in the same div

below is the code for the getdivision.php

```
    <div id="record"></div>
  <form id='form4' action='viewrecord.php' method='POST'>
<table id='table-2'>
    <thead>
        <th>RATE</th>
        <th>LAST NAME</th>
        <th>FIRST NAME</th>
        <th>DIVISION</th>
        <th>WORKCENTER</th>
        <th>MENTOR</th>
        <th>View</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

 <?php 
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {
 echo "<tr>";
 echo "<td>" . $row[0] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row[1] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row[2] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row[3] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row[4] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row[5] . " " . $row[6] . " " . $row[7] . "</td>"
    echo "<td><input type='submit'  name='viewrecord' value='".$row[8]."' class='submit-                           button view-record' /></td>";
      echo "</tr>";
      }
    echo "
    <tbody>
    </table>
    </form>";
```

here is the ajax code

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js">        </script>
    <script>
    $("#form4").submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $.post( viewrecord.php, $("#form4").serialize(), function(data){
            $("results").html(data);
        });
    });
    </script>
```

i can not seem to find the problem

form4 is beging generated from a php script and placed in the #result div of the main page could that be the reason some on please help

here is the index.php that contains the results div

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function showdivision(str)
    {
    if (str=="")
      {
      document.getElementById("results").innerHTML="";
      return;
      } 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        document.getElementById("results").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","getdivision.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }

    function viewrecord()
    {

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        document.getElementById("results").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","viewrecord.php");
    xmlhttp.send();
    }

    </script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","mykoll_frc","frcfrc");
    if (!$con)
      {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
      }


    ?>
    <form>

    <select name="DIVISIONS" onchange="showdivision(this.value)">
    <option value="">Select a Division:</option>
    <option value="600">Avionics</option>
    <option value="700">Armament</option>
    <option value="GMD">GMD</option>
    <option value="ADMIN">ADMIN</option>
    </select>
    <?php
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($mentors))
    {
      echo "<option value=\"".$row['mentorid']."\">".$row['M_RATE']."         ".$row['M_LastName']."                 ".$row['M_FirstName']."\n  ";
    }
    ?>

    </select>

    <button type="button" onclick="showall()">View all records</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="showallmentors()">View Mentor List</button>

    </form>
    <br />
    <div id="results"><b>info will be listed here.</b></div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

the way it is supposed to work is 
the index.php loads
user selects a division
results div is populated from the getdivision.php dynamicallly
then user can select a record and the record should populate the results div 
i hope i said that clear

Comment: i don't see a "results" div, nor a "results" **tag**

Comment: @joseph i updated the question with the index.php code
the way it is supposed to work is 
the index.php loads
user selects a division
results div is populated from the getdivision.php dynamicallly
then user can select a record and the record should populate the results div 
i hope i said that clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery needs the `#` on selectors.

```
$.post( viewrecord.php, $("#form4").serialize(), function(data){
    $("#results").html(data); // changed results to #results
});
```

Comment: thanks for catching that error but that did not solve the problem the form still displays viewrecord.php with page reload